# Facebook Pages: Add multiple Tabs or Links to the left menu

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-page

you all may know, there are some FB apps for creating tabs or links on the left menu of a FB fanpage. tabpress is such an app.

you can add multiple tabs with different content, for example iframe, youtube video, contact forms,  ...

how this apps are done? do I need an own app for each type of tab?
which FB api functions add the tabs to left side?

does anybody have some input? I want to create an app like tabpress.

Answer (score 1):

Please read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ for how to develop page tabs.  For a tab to have a different name, it will also need to be a different app. So in your case, you will have multiple apps.

Answer (score 0):

William, use this FB URL http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=ENTER-YOUR-APP-ID-HERE&pages where you replace ENTER-YOUR-APP-ID-HERE with actually APP ID. Then just submit that by selecting one of your pages and you're done.